# Using Rxjs5 (Beta) to cap http requests

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using RxJS5 (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS) and I'm trying to access the Riot API which has a cap rate of 500 requests every 10 minutes and 10 requests every 10 seconds.

I set up a stream of request objects and I have a subscriber ready to get them and actually request them, but I'm kinda new at RxJS and not sure which operator I should use to cap the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to balance your requests you can use sample:

`const newRequests = requestStream.sample(Observable.timer(75)); //10*60*60/500 = 72 --> 75 to be sure`

Sample will emit an element from the observable, when the given observable emits

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way but I ended up zipping the request objest stream with an interval observer so it will stream events only when the interval ticks.
again, not sure if it's the best way to do this but it works, here's what it looks like:

```
raw_stream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent EventEmitter, 'event'
interval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
timed_events = Rx.Observable.zip interval, raw_stream
```

if you have a better way please feel free to answer.